# Which preposition should follow facilitate?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

Students should be facilitated to access on-line support.

Students should be facilitated in accessing on-line support.

Staff should facilitate students to access on-line support.

Comment: You *facilitate* an action or process. There is no preposition - *staff will facilitate access to online support*. It becomes a real mouthful if you try to add *students*. I think the word you want is *assist* or just *help*.

Comment: Avoid the word. Use something simple Anglo-Saxon and familiar, like “help”.

Comment: @David There is another possible meaning of "facilitated" which is "enabled" rather than "helped". This would mean that the on-line support is made available by the staff rather than that the staff assist the students in the process. I agree, however, that "facilitate" is incorrect.

Comment: @BoldBen — I was making a point about using simple English rather than giving a comprehensive answer. Writers should think what they are trying to say and ask themselves whether they can express it in simple direct English.

Comment: facilitate is being used incorrectly here. David's comments are the best...

Answer (score 1):

None of the sentences are, in my view, grammatical.

But you could say "The staff should facilitate access to on-line support for students". It is not the "students" who are being facilitated, but "access for students". You can facilitate a process, an event, an action, or a result etc., but you cannot, in my opinion facilitate a person.

But "enable" works differently. You could say "The staff should enable students to access on-line support". It is a more versatile word, because you could also "enable access for students".

Answer (score 0):

The staff should **facilitate students in accessing the** on-line support.

Mods, can we rephrase the sentence for enhancement?

Students should be provided with the facility of accessing the on-line support.

Comment: Hello, Zincha. The use of a human beneficiary thematic relation with the verb 'facilitate' (ie a direct object like 'students' or 'people') is something I'm not familiar with. Can you give a source endorsing this (eg an example from a dictionary)?

Answer (score 0):

Staff should facilitate students' access to online support.

You can avoid the issue entirely and make the statement clearer and shorter by recasting the sentence:
--Students should be able to access online support.
--Students should be helped to access online support.
--Staff should help students access online support.

Comment: Hello, Edi. I couldn't agree more, but good 'answers' on ELU (even when they're correct) require decent references showing that they're more than just personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I think students should be 'enabled' to do something in the future.  I also think that staff should help facilitate a student's access to on-line support.  However, I would hope that the students were facilitated to do something in the past.

Facilitated is the past participle, so its use to describe a future event is incorrect.

Comment: Facilitate is not that common in hardware domain.  In server/network management people often use 'provide', like, "Staff should provide online access support to students." As an alternative, "Staff should enable online access support for students."